Achieved SNR is different than the simulation results
I have designed a transimpedance amplifier as follows:

Based on the simulation, I should get around 58 dB for SNR @3MHz:

But what I achieved in my experimental results is as follows:

Supply voltage     +/-1.5 V

Power consumption   900 µA (datasheet=950 µA)


Output signal:

Noise:

Calculations:
-〖Signal〗_RMS= 3.8 mV
-〖Noise〗_RMS= 0.25 mv
-SNR (MATLAB)= 23.4 dB  (I used snr() function in MATLAB to calculate the SNR)
-SNR (Calculated)= 20log(〖Signal〗_RMS/ 〖Noise〗_RMS)= 23.6 dB  (calculation by hand)
Circuit design:
4-layer PCB

3D view:

Schematic:

So, the achieved SNR is 23.4 dB, but what should I get based on simulation is totally different 58 dB, would you please let me know why there is this much difference in the experimental and simulation results?

Take an FFT of your noise and see if there is something specific there. Show us details of your hardware - is it a PCB? Breadboard? What filtering and decoupling do you have on your board?

@Tom Carpenter thank you for your comment, I added the PCB and the schematic details in the post.

How do you know the theoretical SNR? Is it just the SNR of amplifier, SNR of the whole electrical circuit alone, or SNR of random photons hitting the sensor, or is there a signal which gets some noise gets applied before photodiode sees it? (Assuming th sensor is a photodiode. You don't say what sensor it is).

@Justme thank you for the comment, the sensor is an ultrasound transducer, which is can produce a very tiny output current in rang of 100-200uA, I assume this is the SNR of the transimpedance amplifier.

@Andromeda The transducer may pick up noie but even in pure rest state it is a noisy source, the tranmission line to amplifier is noisy, the amplifier itself is noisy, and even the feedback resistor generates thermal noise. Now depending on where the noise is generated, it gets added and/or amplified to the signal.


The PCB designations do not match with the circuit diagram. 2) The circuit diagram does not show R1 in series with the input. 3) There are no decoupling capacitors close to the power pins of the chip. 4) There is a PCB layout error on J2P1@Andromeda


@RussellH thank you for your comment, the PCB does matches the schematic, the decoupling capacitors are on on the bottom layer. regarding J2P1 is ok, it the power rail of the amplifier.
